# How do abort parent ajax call in before send method of ajaxsetup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using multiple ajax call. But using `AjaxSetUp` to know whether call is allowed or not , if not then trying to abort this in `beforeSend`method.

here is ajax call

```
                      $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url : "/apps/doAction",
                            xhrFields : "checkIfAllowed",
                            success : function(response,xhr) {
                            if(response){
                                return false;
                            }
                            },
                            error : function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError) {
                            }
                        });
```

And here is `AjaxSetUp`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(event, xhr, settings) {
                event.xhrToAbort=xhr;
                if(xhr.xhrFields == "checkIfAllowed"){
                     $.ajax({
                            type : "POST",
                            url : contextpath+ "/apps/auth/isAllowed",
                            success : function(response,xhr) {
                            if(response){
                             //  ABORT PARENT CALL ("URL: /apps/doAction") unable to abort parent call..
                            }
                            },
                            error : function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError) {
                            }
                        });
                }
            },
            complete: function(event, xhr, settings) {
                $('.trans-overlay').hide();
             }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

By replacing `event.xhrToAbort=xhr;` to  `event.xhrToAbort=event;`
and where you want to abort use like `event.xhrToAbort.abort();`